# How to change the version of Jetty in my Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, jetty

Within IntelliJ I have a Google App Engine Standard Local Server running. I'm in the process of updating to Java 17 and also all of my 3rd party libraries and have moved to Jetty 11.0.11 in all of my project's pom files. However, when I start up the server I see:
INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.46.v20220331
and I'm getting failures that seem to confirm the above, that an older version of Jetty is being used.
Where can I update the Jetty version that the app engine uses?
Also, I'm using Google appengine 2.0.5

Here's the stack trace. The latest versions should be using jakarta.ws.rs.Path instead of javax.

> java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.ws.rs.Path not present
> at
> java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:47)
> at
> java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:89)
> at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy2.value(Unknown Source)  at
> org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.createServletContainerInitializerAnnotationHandlers(AnnotationConfiguration.java:579)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:343)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:498)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:916)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)   at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
> at
> com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:366)

Comment: Hello Mike! It's a good practice here at Stack Overflow that if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To update the Jetty version to the latest one, I would suggest updating the Cloud SDK to the latest version. Based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes), the most recent release of Cloud SDK is version 395.0.0 (2022-07-26) and according to the  [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/release-notes), the latest Java SDK version is 1.9.98 and latest [Jetty version](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.php) is 11.0.11

I would recommend trying to upgrade the Cloud SDK by following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/components#updating_components) so the Jetty version is updated to the latest one.

**EDIT:** If you think it’s a valid feature request you may raise [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/) with a clear description why you are thinking it’s a feature request. Good feature requests will solve common problems or enable new use cases.

Comment: From what I've read: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/release-notes  the latest app engine only supports jetty-9.4.46.v20220331.